# Show Change Record Type in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to know if it is possible to show the change record type window in LWC. I have a lead record type that allow a user to enter info with minimal required fields. And then when this lead is ready for conversion, the user should complete the details by changing the record type. I have a custom convert button that will require a user to change the record type to be able to fill the required fields first before conversion. I want to user to be prompted with this when that button is clicked. [image]

Thanks,
Du

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot show the standard change record type window in LWC.
If you want then you can create a similar custom UI in LWC by querying the Lead record types in Apex and then pass into the .js class in order make the LWC dynamic.